# maven persistent add jar to local project

Tags: git, maven, configuration, include, local

i'm having yet another issue with maven project configuration.I have to include an external .jar file within the maven project that is also a git project, and i want it both to be in the remote git repo.I have to itemize that the jar is the output of another maven project (a clone of https://github.com/perwendel/spark) but i don't know if this really matter.Currently i tried to use a plugin, exactly

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>add-jars</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>../src/main/resources/</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>spark-0.9.9.5.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

and then

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
     <version>0.9.9.5</version> 
</dependency>
```

then i git-push the main maven project with its pom.xml and ../src/main/resources/ to have it done, but there are project related to my local maven repo.In fact when i git-clone the tree from another location the maven build fails due to:

## ...

## The POM for spark:spark:jar:0.9.9.5 is missing, no dependency information available

## ...

## ...

## Failure to find spark:spark:jar:0.9.9.5 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached #in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of #central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

i'm not really keen on maven, am i missing something?wrong plugins?thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to me that you didn't understand the purpose of Maven. Maven's purpose is to define the dependencies between project.
In your case to use the spark you just need to put the dependency in your pom as you mentioned:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
     <version>0.9.9.5</version> 
</dependency>
```

The problem here is that the people who are developing spark didn't go the step into Maven Central.
What you simply need to do is clone the git repository of them and do

```
  mvn install
```

afterwards this version of the artifact is available for your projects. To solve those kind of issues is to setup a repository manager (Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva) and deploy this kind of artifacts into this repository.

The message you have means that you are trying to use a dependency which is not available in Maven central. The solution is to mvn install as described above but before delete the directory **${HOME}/.m2/repository/spark**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think is out of topic, i have to include an external .jar file within the maven project that is also a git project, and i want it both to be in the remote git repo.I got it working locally (the main project using my custom spark project build) but i want the spark-custom to be bundled with the main project, since it is just a jar i was trying to bundle it in the main maven project.